# Get the same clients by phone number or email

Tags: sql, database

I have the clients with E-mail and Phone fields in my database. Some of them have both phone and email, some of them only email, some of them only phone. Phones and email can be not unique between different clients.

I need to create virtual table, where the database will count the clients with the same email or phone as the one same client. For example, I have the table:

```
Phone  Email   ID
916    x@.com  1
       x@.com  2
916            3
915            4
```

The query should create the 4th column, which will display the unique same value for the clients with IDs 1, 2 and 3.

Result should be somthing like

```
Phone  Email   ID  NewID
916    x@.com  1   1
       x@.com  2   1
916            3   1
915            4   2
917    x@.com  5   1
917    y@.en   6   1
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as a table, formatted text here too.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, there may be different solutions for each

Comment: Will there always be a record that has both a phone and e-mail? And is there perhpas an extra column that would have the same value for the  records that can be used in a group by? Like f.e. ClientName?

Comment: Any DBMS would fit, I just need an idea how to do that (MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, any). In most cases there won't be the record with both  phone and e-mail. And no extra columns with the same values :( If there is two records with the phone, I need a unique ID for them, if there is two records with only email i need a unique Id for them.

Comment: Will there only be missing values or could it be, for example, that there's also an entry with phone=123 and email=x@.com?

Comment: Please define the rules for every possible data set.  What if (917   , x@.com, 5) is added? which Newid will  (null, x@.com , 2)  get?

Comment: Edited just now. Thank you.

Comment: Surely you should have a reflective symmetry in your result set? Or is there some direction to newness?

Comment: Probably something with `row_number()`

Comment: Can't see how id=6 is similar to id=1 and gets newId =1.

Answer (score 1):

You could self join the table on the phone or email.
Then GROUP BY and use MIN to show the lowest ID.

Example:

```
select t.Phone, t.Email, t.ID, min(t2.ID) as NewID
from YourTable t
left join YourTable t2 on (t2.Email = t.Email or t2.Phone = t.Phone)
group by t.ID, t.Phone, t.Email
```

Example result:

```
Phone Email  ID NewID
----- ------ -- -----
916   x@.com 1  1
NULL  x@.com 2  1
916   NULL   3  1
915   NULL   4  4
NULL  y@.com 5  5
```

But to get that expected result?
Where the link to the phone has priority, even if it's NULL?
You could use an extra self join :

Example:

```
select t.Phone, t.Email, t.ID, coalesce(min(t3.ID), min(t2.ID)) as NewID
from YourTable t
left join YourTable t2 on (t2.Email = t.Email or t2.Phone = t.Phone)
left join YourTable t3 on (t3.Email = t2.Email or (t.Email is null and t3.Email is not null and t3.Phone is null))
group by t.ID, t.Phone, t.Email
```

Example result:

```
Phone Email   ID NewID
----- ------- -- -----
916   x@.com  1  1
NULL  x@.com  2  1
916   NULL    3  1
915   NULL    4  2
917   x@.com  5  1
917   y@.en   6  1
```

Answer (score 1):

erm,

```
SELECT
          T.[Id]
          T.[Phone]
          T.[Email]
          E.[Id] [NewId]    
   FROM
          [Table] T
       JOIN
          [Table] E
              ON T.[Email] = E.[Email]
UNION
SELECT
          T.[Id]
          T.[Phone]
          T.[Email]
          P.[Id] [NewId]    
   FROM
          [Table] T
       JOIN
          [Table] P
              ON T.[Phone] = P.[Phone];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks like you the new column is just the `min(id)` of rows with same phone or phone number

so

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.phone, a.email, a.id, min(b.id) 
from clients a join clients b on (a.phone = b.phone OR a.email = b.email)
```

Comment: This will result in an error as you need to group by `a.phone, a.email, a.id`